# set<shared_ptr<T>>::iterator to set<shared_ptr<T const>>::const_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, type-conversion, constants

So I have seen the [questions about casting `std::shared_ptr<T>` to `std::shared_ptr<T const>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616586) and that is working well so far. But I have another question. I'd like to return an interator to my `std::set<std::shared_ptr<T>>`, where both the `T` and the `std::shared_ptr` is const. I have been unable to convert them straight over, or with any of the casts. I get the following error:

```
error: no viable conversion from returned value of type
'_Rb_tree_const_iterator<shared_ptr<tuple<...>>>' to function return type
'_Rb_tree_const_iterator<shared_ptr<const tuple<...>>>'
      return ptrLut.begin();
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

One of the walkarounds I see is storing a `union` of `std::set<std::shared_ptr<T>>` and `std::set<std::shared_ptr<T const>>`, but I feel like that is probably not the proper solution to this. I just wanted to know if there is a good way to do this cast?

Comment: Could you provide the code which generated that error? And what do you mean by an iterator where T and std::shared_ptr are const? An iterator to a std::set<const std::shared_ptr<const int>>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else: After a few days of thinking, this is the solution I came up with.

An Iterator class template to hold the real iterator, not letting anyone touch it.

```
template<typename It>
struct Iterator {
  Iterator(It &&it) : setIt(it) { }

  Iterator &operator++() {
    ++setIt;
    return *this;
  }

  T const &operator*() {
    return **setIt;
  }

  bool operator==(Iterator<It> const &other) {
    return setIt == other.setIt;
  }

  bool operator!=(Iterator<It> const &other) {
    return setIt != other.setIt;
  }

  std::shared_ptr<T const> ptr() {
    return *setIt;
  }
private:
  It setIt;
};
```

and then simply doing

```
auto begin() const {
  return Iterator<typename std::set<std::shared_ptr<T>>::iterator>(ptrLut.begin());
}

auto end() const {
  return Iterator<typename std::set<std::shared_ptr<T>>::iterator>(ptrLut.end());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`set<A>` is unrelated to `set<B>`, even if `A` is implicitly convertible to `B`, so you **can't** get a `set<shared_ptr<T const>>::const_iterator` from a `set<shared_ptr<T>>::iterator`.

The best you can do is with something like [`boost::transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html), with a function to add const-ness. This will suffice unless the iterator is *required to be* `set<shared_ptr<T const>>::const_iterator`, rather than just *having the same behaviour as*

E.g.

```
#include <set>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

std::shared_ptr<T const> add_const (std::shared_ptr<T> ptr) { return ptr; };

int main()
{
    std::set<std::shared_ptr<T>> the_set;
    auto cbegin = boost::make_transform_iterator(std::as_const(the_set).begin(), add_const);
    auto cend = boost::make_transform_iterator(std::as_const(the_set).end(), add_const);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well that would cause a lot of copies of each shared_ptr though, right? And those aren't the best thing to copy in an iteration as far as I know. The other answer does let these conversions happen from iterator to iterator, kind of what I was hoping for.

Comment: Any solution is going to involve constructing `shared_ptr<T const>` instances from `shared_ptr<T>` instances, because they are *distinct types*. This defers that transformation to the point at which the iterator is dereferenced.